# Can't access a property in constructor function

Tags: javascript, function, constructor, this

I have a constructor function with some properties and prototypes. However, by some reason I can't access the properties in on of the prototype functions.

Below is some code (reduced the code so it's readable) just to show you what I mean. In the function 'renderTiles' I can access 'pairs', but in 'turnTile' I can't. Is there an obvious reason for this or is it impossible to find out with through my reduced code?

UPDATE: Updated the code to make it more clear...

```
DESKTOP.Game = function(){
    this.pairs = 0;
}

DESKTOP.Game.prototype.renderTiles = function() {

console.log(this.pairs); <- undefined

var gamearea = $('<div/>', {
    'text': 'testarea',
    'class': 'gamearea'
}).appendTo('.memory:last');

alert("this.rows: " + this.rows);

for (var j = 0; j < this.rows; j++){
    var box = document.createElement('div');
    for (var i = 0; i < this.cols; i++){

        var iterator = (this.cols * j) + i;

        var img = document.createElement('img');
        var aNod = document.createElement('a');

        aNod.href = "#";
        img.src = "pics/memory/0.png";

        aNod.appendChild(img);
        box.appendChild(aNod);

        var self = this;
        (function(place, index) {
            this.addEventHandler(aNod, 'click', function() { this.turnTile(place, index); return false; });
        })(iterator, this.imgArray[iterator]);
    }   
    gamearea[0].appendChild(box);
}
}

DESKTOP.Game.prototype.turnTile = function(place, id) {
    console.log(this.pairs); <- undefined

// removed code...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the value of `this` depends on *how* you call `turnTiles`.

Because you're doing:

```
DESKTOP.Game.prototype.turnTile(place, index)
```

...the value of `this` will be the `prototype` object, but `pairs` is placed on each individual object created from `Game`, not on the `prototype`.

I have no idea how you're calling `renderTiles`, but I'd assume that you created an instance of `Game` and called from there.

Not knowing how your code works, I'd just guess that you want `addEventHandler` to be called on the instance as well.

If so, you'd replace this:

```
(function(place, index) {
    DESKTOP.Game.prototype.addEventHandler(aNod, 'click', function() { DESKTOP.Game.prototype.turnTile(place, index); return false; });
})(iterator, this.imgArray[iterator]);
```

with this:

```
var self = this;
(function(place, index) {
    self.addEventHandler(aNod, 'click', function() { self.turnTile(place, index); return false; });
})(iterator, this.imgArray[iterator]);
```

or something.

Though I'm not sure why you're using an IIFE here unless you're in a loop.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I tried "var self = this" but get the following error message in the console: "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object DOMWindow] has no method 'addEventHandler'".

Comment: @JasonCraig: That's because you need `self.addEventHandler` and `self.turnTile`. You have `this.addEventHandler` and `this.turnTile`.